# BGE Animation problem

Tags: animation, game-engine

I am having a few problems in BGE in relation to animations.

1. I have a parent and a parented object. When I move the parent in the game, the child objects move fine, but as soon as they have to play an animation, they go to their original parenting place, and play the animation there.
2. I have a helicopter animation. When the helicopter needs to go faster, it rotates on the y-axis. However, in the game, when I rotate the helicopter, as soon as I play the animation, the helicopter snaps back into the angle it was animated. When I change the action actuator to 'add', when the animation plays, the helicopter flips upside down.

I must apologize, but I do not know how to attach a blend file. If necessary, you can tell me.

Comment: [https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) there you can upload blend files, use [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/89947/edit) to paste the link in your question. also you may want to add somes images of the dope sheet or action editor and more. Have nice day.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please keep only one question per post, ask as many as necessary

Comment: I figured It out! When I have to play an animation, I need to change the actuator to add, or local. I think this is it. Thanks!